# Page down with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How do I perform a "page down" operation with Javascript/jQuery so that it **works correctly if the user has zoomed in/out**?

i.e. it should scroll no more and no less than would happen if the user had actually pressed the key, whether or not the user had messed up the zoom settings or fonts or DPI or whatever.

#### Notes:

- There may not be any particular element at the target position. I just want to "page down", not caring whether there's a particular element at the destination. (i.e. I can't use `scrollTo`.)
- Also, animation would be great, but not required. :)

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve that this needs to be rendered to pixel perfection? It's impossible to override that default browser behaviour.

Comment: @Jordan: Your second sentence makes a good answer (although not one I was hoping for); your first sentence is a bit lame, though (sorry). My whole purpose is to avoid custom UIs, and keep the behavior of the system/browser the same. Why should I settle for something less than what I want (unless it's literally impossible otherwise)?

Comment: Well I wasn't meaning it condescendingly, I was just trying to understand what you're actually trying to do, with the hope that maybe there's another approach. My 2nd sentence is more appropriately redefined as "it's impossible to override that default browser behaviour consistently, cross browser".

Comment: @Jordan: Ah. Well if it's literally impossible then never mind; I was hoping it wasn't.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height());
```

EDIT: as per your comment

I'm not able to trigger the native page down functionality with javascript, and since we can't assume that every browser and every operating system will handle pagedown to the exact same number of pixels, I suppose that means you can't do it.

Comment: Does this work with zooming? And does it do **exactly** what the key does?

Comment: Check it out.... it's not that hard to test yourself, in my opinion yes... within a reasonable margin of error (a few pixels)

Comment: Sure, I'll try it out. But it looks to me as though your example goes down **literally** one page, whereas Page Down/Up always leave some overlap. (Edit: "A reasonable margin of error" is **not** "exactly what the key does", by definition... that's the whole point of the question. -1)